# Showing that a derivable function $f$ (satisfying some conditions) is null.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, riemann-integration

Enunciate:

- Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ derivable, such that $f(0)=0$ and, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, satisfy $f'(x)=(f(x))^2$. Prove that $f\equiv 0$.

How can I prove it? I'm trying to integrate something in someway, but nothing that I tried works.

Comment: what is $[x]$ - greatest integer function?

Comment: typically, Taylor's theorem is key for things like this, but not sure it will help here...

Comment: @gt6989b no! Its nothing

Comment: See this and use the same idea: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1645866/254733

Comment: @gt6989b hm.. I will try.

Comment: @Svetoslav I will check it!

Comment: Just show that $|f(x)|\leq M^2\frac{|x|^n}{n!}$ and therefore $f$ must be equal to $0$ in any finite interval, containing $0$

Comment: @Svetoslav I got it! Thanks Svetolasv!

Comment: You could assume that $f(x_0)\neq 0$ for some $x_0$ and solve the differential equation, show that $f(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: @Svetoslav I found $|f(x)|\leq M\frac{(Mx)^{n+1}}{n!}$, what works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use uniform continuity. Let $a>0$ be fixed, and let's show that $f$ is zero on $[0,a]$. Note that since $f'=f^2\geq 0$, $f$ is non-decreasing. Chose $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ in $[0,a]$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<1$. We can assume $\delta<1$. Let $0=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=a$ be a partition of $[0,a]$ with $|x_i-x_{i+1}|<\delta$. Let's show that $f(x_i)=0$ for all $i$ by induction. The case $i=0$ is from the hypothesis. If $f(x_i)=0$, then $f(x_{i+1})<1$, so
$$f(x_{i+1})=\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f'(t)dt=\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}f(t)^2dt\leq(x_{i+1}-x_i)f(x_{i+1})^2$$
If $f(x_{i+1})$ were not zero, this would imply $1<\delta$, a contradiction.

Therefore, $f(x_i)=0$ for all $i$. In particular, $f(a)=f(x_n)=0$. Since $a>0$ is arbitrary, we see that $f(x)=0$ for $x\geq 0$.

Considering the function $g(x)=f(-x)$, $g$ also satisfies the hypothesis of the question, so the previous argument implies $g(x)=0$ for $x\geq 0$, that is, $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$.

Comment: Great answer, Luiz! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f\not \equiv 0.$ Then the set where $f \ne 0$ is open (by continuity) and nonempty, hence is a pairwise disjoint union of open intervals. Suppose one of these intervals has the form $(a,b),$ where $a\in \mathbb R, b \in (a,\infty].$ Then in $(a,b)$ we have

$$-\frac{1}{f(x)} = x + c$$

for some constant $c.$ Why? Because the derivative of the left side equals the derivative of the right side on this interval. This implies the limit of the left side is finite as $x\to a^+.$ That is a contradiction, since $f(a) = 0.$

The other possibility, where $a \in [-\infty,b), b\in \mathbb R,$ is handled similarly.

Comment: It's a great answer, too! Thanks zhw!

Answer (score 3):

Using only “basic” tools: MVT and continuity. No integrals and no differential equations. No $\varepsilon-\delta$.

First observe that since $f'=f^2\geq0$, the function $f$ is non-decreasing. Now:

- Let $x>0$. Then, by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c\in(0,x)$ such that
  $$f(x)=xf'(c)=xf(c)^2\leq xf(x)^2$$
  (since $f(0)=0$, $f$ is non-decreasing and $0<c<x$).
  If $f(x)\neq0$, then $f(x)>0$ (since $x>0$, $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is non-decreasing) and hence
  $$1\leq xf(x).$$
- Let $x<0$, there exists $c\in(x,0)$ such that
  $$f(x)=xf'(c)=xf(c)^2\geq xf(x)^2$$
  (since $f$ is non-decreasing, $x<c<0$). If $f(x)\neq0$ then
  $f(x)<0$ (since $x<0$, $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is non-decreasing), and hence
  $$1\leq xf(x).$$

Conclusion: for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$f(x)=0\qquad\text{or}\qquad 1\leq xf(x).$$
Since the function $x\mapsto xf(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ (and its value is $0$ at $0$), we conclude (a full justification could be done using the Intermediate Value Theorem) that
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ xf(x)=0,$$
and hence (by continuity of $f$ at $0$), $f$ is nil.

Comment: This is a really great one! Thanks gniourf_gniourf!!

Comment: I think it needs more justification, because from $f'(x)\ge 0$ doesn't follow that  there isn't some interval $[0,a]$ where it is zero and then starting increasing. Then the result after the division by $f(x)$ above will be true only in some interval $(b,c)$ where $a<b$ (because if $f(x)>0$ for some $x>a$ by continuity, $f(x)>0$ for a whole neighborhood of that $x$, which I called $(b,c)$

Comment: @Svetoslav: You're write, but this doesn't invalidate the argument: I wrote the conclusion as an alternative: $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ \bigl(f(x)=0\ \text{or}\ 1\leq xf(x)\bigr)$. I didn't write: $\bigl(\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ f(x)=0\bigr)\ \text{or}\ \bigl(\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ 1\leq xf(x)\bigr)$.

Comment: @Svetoslav: and then I'm using the continuity of the function $g:x\mapsto xf(x)$ and the fact that $g(0)=0$ to conclude that $g$ is nil; and hence that $f$ is nil.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I didn't mean that it is not valid, just made a point,  probably because I didn't get it correctly, as you pointed out in your comment with the alternative. +1